# ORA-06550: line 6, column 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE"

Tags: plsql

I allow myself to contact you because I have been trying to solve this error for several hours but I can't do it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PurgeMembres 
AS 
BEGIN   
   DELETE FROM Membre
   WHERE MONTHS_BETWEEN(Date_adhesion, sysdate) >36;     
END; /
```

I have the error :

> ORA-06550: line 6, column 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
>   "CREATE"

Here is the creation of the Members table :

```
 CREATE TABLE Membre(   
 Num INTEGER,   
 Nom varchar2(50) NOT NULL,     
 Prenom varchar2(50) NOT NULL,  
 Adresse varchar2(200) NOT NULL,    
 Telephone char(10),    
 Date_adhesion DATE NOT NULL,   
 Duree number NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT membre_pk PRIMARY KEY (Num),    
 CONSTRAINT duree_c CHECK
 (Duree IN (1, 3, 6, 12)) );
```

Thank you

I alto tried putting the / on a new line but I still have this same error . Currently, I use Oracle Live SQL online at this address: livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:1000:113480930147730:::::

Comment: Welcome to SO, please add as much detail about the problem you are facing to allow others to help you better.

Comment: @jimmy8ball Hello, I think my problem is due to a syntax error because this error is found on all my other functions and procedures as follows

Comment: OK but what are you trying to do in terms of the workflow?

Comment: here, the goal is to have Date_adhesion greater than 36 months

Comment: Which tool do you use to run the CREATE PROCEDURE statement? Usually the `/` needs to be on a separate line (at least with the default Oracle tools)

Comment: I alto tried putting the / on a new line but I still have this same error  . Currently, I use Oracle Live SQL online at this address: https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:1000:113480930147730:::::

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your procedure. I suggest you to write it from scratch by typing via keyboard and see what will happen.

Sometimes unwanted / unforseen characters can be added in your procedure when you copy/paste part of the procedure from 3rd party sources. I encountered with this kind of issues many times.

It may sometimes relate with your GUI tool as well.

The below code definitely needs to work:

> ```
>  CREATE TABLE Membre(   
>  Num INTEGER,   
>  Nom varchar2(50) NOT NULL,     
>  Prenom varchar2(50) NOT NULL,  
>  Adresse varchar2(200) NOT NULL,    
>  Telephone char(10),    
>  Date_adhesion DATE NOT NULL,   
>  Duree number NOT NULL,
>  CONSTRAINT membre_pk PRIMARY KEY (Num),    
>  CONSTRAINT duree_c CHECK
>  (Duree IN (1, 3, 6, 12)) );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
>     CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PurgeMembres AS 
>     BEGIN   
>        DELETE FROM Membre
>        WHERE MONTHS_BETWEEN(Date_adhesion, sysdate) >36;    
>     END; 
>     /
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ee74cd65a7be962c1ef6a9620816066d)*

Comment: Even if I copy (not copy and paste) the creation of my table and the function, I still have the same error

Comment: which editor are you using? did you try to write it with keyboard withour C/P?

Comment: I use visual studio code but by taking your advice (not to copy and paste), I still have the same mistake

Comment: IT is even working here https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/hxqf4e7pfjqhx9oskw6f7nxw9

Comment: you must be kidding. same piece of code working for me and not for you? seriously!!!

Comment: If I tell you, it's the truth, I would never make fun of anyone who takes their free time to help other people in difficulty. All in all, we have redesigned the function and now it works.